# Show that the sequence $p_{n+1}=p_{n}+\frac{1}{2}(t-p_{n}^2)$ is increasing.

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

Let $p_0=0$, $t\in[0,1]$ and $p_{n+1}(t):=p_{n+1}=p_{n}+\frac{1}{2}(t-p_{n}^2)$ be a sequence, I must show that it is increasing, that is $p_n\leq p_{n+1}$.

If it were to be increasing then by the relation we have that:
$$p_n\leq p_{n+1}\iff p_{n}^2\leq t$$

How would I show that $p_n^2\leq t$ I tried induction but I get stuck.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: @SebastianCor FYI, the same sequence you're asking about, but formulated as a sequence of polynomials and different aspects about them are requested, are in [How to show that $P_n : [0, 1] \rightarrow \Bbb R$; $P_{n+1}(x) = P_n(x) + \frac{1}{2}(x-P_n^2(x))$ converges uniformly to $\sqrt{x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1517787/602049) and [Recurrent problem about polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1065949/602049).

Comment: @SebastianCor If you add what you've tried to your question text, we can then better help you to get unstuck.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I'm reading the references you linked, as per adding my attempt I just tried some manipulations that didn't pan out that's why I opted to leave them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach to your problem. As in your OP, define
\begin{align}
p_0(t)\equiv0\qquad p_{n+1}(t)=\tfrac12(t+2p_n(t)-(p_n(t))^2).
\end{align}

An simple algebraic manipulation yields
\begin{align}
2(p_{n+1}(t)-\sqrt{t})&=(2-p_n(t))p_n(t)-(2-\sqrt{t})\sqrt{t}\tag{1}\label{one}\\
2(p_{n+1}(t)-p_n(t))&=t-(p_n(t))^2\tag{2}\label{two}
\end{align}
The function $\varphi(x)=(2-x)x$ is monotone increasing on $[0,1]$ ($\varphi'(x)=2(1-x)>0$ for all $0\leq x<1$). Hence, if  $0\leq p_n(t)\leq \sqrt{t}$, then  \eqref{one} we would imply $0\leq p_{n+1}(t)\leq\sqrt{t}$.  Since $0=p_0(t)\leq\sqrt{t}$, then  $0\leq p_1(t)\leq\sqrt{t}$. Continuing by induction, we have that
$$\begin{align}
0\leq p_n(t)\leq\sqrt{t},\qquad 0\leq t\leq 1, \quad n\in\mathbb{Z}_+\tag{3}\label{three}\end{align}$$

From \eqref{three}  and  \eqref{two} it follows that
$$0\leq p_n(t)\leq p_{n+1}(t)\leq\sqrt{t}$$
This shows that $p_n(t)$ converges for any $t$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Again, from \eqref{two} we obtain that  $\lim_np_n(t)=\sqrt{t}$. Furthermore, convergence is uniform by [Dini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem).

Comment: How does $(1)$ imply $p_{n+1}(t)\leq \sqrt(t)$?

Comment: The right-hand side of (1) is $\varphi(p_n)-\varphi(\sqrt{t})$ (valid if $0\leq p_n(t)\leq 1$, which holds by inductive assumption: $0\leq p_n(t)\leq\sqrt{t}\leq 1$) and $\varphi$ is monotone increasing in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Such a nice and short answer!

Comment: @SebastianCor: In fact, changing $t$ got $t^2$ in the definition of $p_n$ and extending the domain to $|t|\leq1$, (substitute then any appearance of $\sqrt{t}$ by $|t|$, would give you a slightly more interesting result: $p_n(t)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}|t|$ uniformly. Then you can use this to get your result.